# Create a html-js UI GCalendar alike in java

Tags: java, user-interface, calendar

I'm trying to replicate a UI like a gcalendar (only the layout not any of its functions)
  how to build a loop with a calendar to build a cute layout like that? with saturdays marked and holidays too.

Thx

Comment: You mean a UI like Google Calendar? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859012/approach-to-build-a-simple-calendar-in-java-swing

Comment: Mark, not exactly, should be like a iteration over a calendar and output it. the JTable doesn't meet that, im looking more of a algorithm than a component itself.

Comment: Ok but the comments did talk about using JPanels as an alternative. You could use JPanels or even just draw the components yourself at the Java2D level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the java code:

```
public class CalendarUI {
    public static String Dias[] = { "", "DOM", "SEG", "TER", "QUA", "QUI", "SEX", "SAB" };
    public static String Meses[] = { "JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ" };

    public static void printCalendar(int currMonth){
        int i = 1;      
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##00");


        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, currMonth);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, i);

        // cabecalho com o mes
        System.out.println(" - " + Meses[currMonth] + " - ");

        // ajuste para o primeiro dia
        for (; i < c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); i++) {
            System.out.print("           ");
        }

        // principal
        for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, i);

            if (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) == currMonth) {       
                if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1)
                    System.out.println("");

                System.out.print("[ " + Dias[c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]
                        + ", " + formatter.format(i) + " ]");
            }
        }       

        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            CalendarUI.printCalendar(j);

        }

    }
```

---

the output with correct indent of days in months (example given for may):

```
 - MAI - 
                                                       [ SEX, 01 ][ SAB, 02 ]
[ DOM, 03 ][ SEG, 04 ][ TER, 05 ][ QUA, 06 ][ QUI, 07 ][ SEX, 08 ][ SAB, 09 ]
[ DOM, 10 ][ SEG, 11 ][ TER, 12 ][ QUA, 13 ][ QUI, 14 ][ SEX, 15 ][ SAB, 16 ]
[ DOM, 17 ][ SEG, 18 ][ TER, 19 ][ QUA, 20 ][ QUI, 21 ][ SEX, 22 ][ SAB, 23 ]
[ DOM, 24 ][ SEG, 25 ][ TER, 26 ][ QUA, 27 ][ QUI, 28 ][ SEX, 29 ][ SAB, 30 ]
[ DOM, 31 ]
```

Comment: now basically, change the print tags, its possible to ouput the correct html for the UI.